# Why do Google's open font examples look different then when I implement them in the same browser?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

For example, take a look at http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Open+Sans. Inspect the type, change the font size to something smaller like 12px. Now when I implement this font on my own website (in the same browser, i.e. Firefox 10 on Windows 7) it has very poorly rendered edges. I can get the font to look better (but not really acceptable) at 11px, 13px, 15px, etc., but at the link above the font looks perfect at all of those sizes plus even sizes like 12px, 14px, etc.

I've scoured their code for some kind of "rendering intent" rule or something like that but I just don't see it. How the heck are they getting all of their fonts looking so good, even on Windows browsers?

**Edit:** Here's some text that I inserted into Google's preview of the font: https://i.stack.imgur.com/plueI.jpg
And the identically styled item in my own HTML page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHgN4.jpg

The "g", the dots in the "i"s and nearly all of the letters are rendering very poorly.

Comment: I think there may be some interesting rendering happening when a parent element has a % or em based font-size applied to it, although I can't actually demonstrate this via the inspector @ google.com/webfonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the page http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/test/open-sans.html on your browser. It tests Open Sans in a simple environment using the coding recommended by Google. Both the black on white text and grey on white text, in 12px size, look normal on my Firefox. If they look OK to you too, then the problem is in some additional code on your page. In that case, post the code or a URL of a minimal case that still exhibits the problem as you see it.

Comment: I tried the same thing, simple text on a simple page - looks fine in all browsers (which is great, from some of the comments I've been finding I'm surprised that I don't see any issues in IE as others have been reporting). I'll have to extract some of the code in my page until I can reproduce the error and post it here. Thanks.

Comment: It does appear that some outer wrappers that contained % and em specified font sizes was causing this to render poorly in Firefox as well as Chrome on Windows only. Cleaning up all of the wrappers so that everything uses pixels is now giving me clean results.

Comment: @Jukka I'm having trouble with font weight 700 (bold) at 13px, even when using a variant of your test page. See http://pastebin.com/WHWD6yUF - the 'a' and the 'e' are particularly bad (Chrome 24, Windows). Is this just a limitation of the font? `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased` made little difference and `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility` made none.

Comment: @LarsJ, it’s probably just a feature of the rendering, caused by a combination of font face, font size, and browser’s rendering algorithm. Especially in small sizes, rasterization of glyphs may produce poor results. The `-webkit-font-smoothing` property works on Mac only, and `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility` affects only kerning and ligatures, not the basic rendering of glyphs.

Comment: You're right, just tried it on the Mac and it looks much better, although still feels like it doesn't really want to be rendered at that size. I'll probably have to rethink my font choices. Thanks for all the insight. [Edit: font weights 600 and 800 are fine on Windows & Mac, but I really wanted the 700 ;)]